# Paired Data collected; one condition is non-homogenous; Paired t-test possible?

Tags: t-test, heteroscedasticity, paired-data

I collected data on language attitudes to three languages in two moments of time, so the responders were the same. For two languages, the Bartlett test approved the homogeneity of variances, so then I conducted paired t-tests. For the third, the Bartlett test rejects the null hypothesis. Can I still conduct the paired t-test or could you recommend another way to look at the significance of the change in attitude?

Comment: The paired t-test is simply a one-sample t-test on the differences. Hence, there is no assumption concerning homogeneous variances. How does the Q-Q plot of the differences look like?

Comment: @COOLSerdash Thank you for your help! So, that's the difference from a non-paired t-test? In the Q-Q plot the data assemble into a line, not straight, but close to it with non-aligned data on both extremes. But the histogram doesn't look symmetrical with more data towards the higher values. I cannot share the screenshots, can I?

Comment: Should I then use the Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test?

Comment: You can add the QQ plot to your question, yes. If you are interested in the mean, a Wilcoxon Signed Rank test will not test that. So what is your hypothesis?

Comment: My hypothesis is that the current average attitude is lower than the average attitude 5 years ago. N=82, should I actually necessarily check normality (limit theorem)?

Comment: For a statistical test, you need to be more specific. Are you interested in the mean, the median, something else? If you're interested in the mean and doubtful that the assumptions of the paired t test can be met, I'd recommend a permutation test. A t test may be fine too though.